# Full cover $SU(n)$ Lie group globally from the exponential map of local Lie algebra (with appropriate representation)

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, lie-algebras

I saw this question: [Reconstructing Lie group globally from the exponential map](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1140556/955245)
asking whether we can full cover a Lie group $G$ globally given by the local Lie algebra $t$ away from the identity element (of the Lie group), and extend to write the exponential map
$$
\exp(\sum \alpha_a t_a).
$$

What I meant for the full cover is that given any group element $g \in G$, we are always able to find a set of $\alpha_a' $ such that the $g = \exp(\sum \alpha_a' t_a)$.

We also should specify certain dimensions of the matrix representations of the Lie algebra.

There the answer seems to be negative in general.

However, I am more simple-minded. I am curious for the case of $SU(n)$. Can we reconstruct the Lie group globally from the exponential map and the local Lie algebra  of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$? for each $n \geq 2$.

1. For $n=1$, it is a trivial Lie group with only the identity.
2. For $n=2$, if I am not mistaken, we can construct the $SU(2)$ Lie group out of the local $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ Lie algebra. So YES.

To clarify,  I think we can construct the $SU(2)$ by the 2-dimensional representaiton of $\mathfrak{su}(2)=\mathfrak{so}(3).$ However, we can construct the $SO(3)$ by the 3-dimensional representaiton of $\mathfrak{su}(2)=\mathfrak{so}(3).$

3. For $n=3$, if I am not mistaken, we can construct the $SU(3)$ Lie group out of the local $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ Lie algebra?  YES or NO?
4. For general $n$, as above, $\dots$ what is the case?

How about the general $n$, is there a critical $n'$ such that the situation changes from Yes $n<n'$ and No for $n\geq n'$?

Comment: The exponential map on $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is surjective, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427980/the-function-exp-mathfraksun-to-sun-is-surjective?rq=1).

Comment: To clarify, I think we can construct the (2)
by the 2-dimensional representaiton of (2)=(3). However, we can construct the (3) by the 3-dimensional representaiton of (2)=(3). So I do think the global difference of $SU(2)/\mathbf{Z}/2=SO(3) $ is not a main issue, at least in this case. I am not sure in general

Comment: many thanks I upvoted your comment

Comment: I do not know why people voted me down without leaving me a comment for improvement --- this is really bad temper for "welcoming me" to this site :(

Comment: I modify the question to say what I meant for "Full cover the Lie group" instead of reconstruct a Lie group.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, yes your link is relevant

Comment: Is your link's idea based on the complete parametrization of maximal torus basically? (what else to add?)